# Create arff training and test files for weka

Tags: weka, training-data, arff

Good day.
An apology for my English but it's not my native language so they know apologize for any errors.

I have a text file with the data processing which want to get a .arff file, which is the file type using weka.
I do not want to generate a single file. I get 2 files, one for training the model (training) and another to test the model (test).
This is done directly weka eh applying a filter stringtowordtokenizer but the problem is that when you use the second file to test a mistake because it is not fair test a model that has words that should not be.
If someone helps me I would appreciate.
Thank you and best regards.

Comment: is there anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: eh used a filter and also try Zeros fill the places where the attributes do not exist. But in both cases weka not allow me to run the classifier.